# Best way to modify projectile types?

Tags: projectile

I've come to rely a lot on `projectile-toggle-between-implementation-and-test` to jump between implementation and test when developing Clojure. However when I tried to use it in my Haskell projects it didn't work at all. I found that two things needed adjusting.

1. The project type was wrongly set to `make`. I fixed that by explicitly setting it to `haskell-cabal` in my `.dir-locals.el`:

   ```
   ((nil . ((projectile-project-type . haskell-cabal))))
   ```
2. Second, the test suffix, `Spec`, didn't match what I use so I put this in my config:

   ```
   (with-eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
     (plist-put (alist-get 'haskell-cabal projectile-project-types)
                'test-suffix "Test"))
   ```

I'm not very experienced with configuring Emacs, so I'm wondering if this is a good way of doing it, or if there's a better way?

Comment: The question risks being closed as primarily opinion-based. Instead of asking for the best way, or is there a better way, try asking a *specific question* about your actual code.

Comment: Please clarify what notion of "good/bad" you're interested in.  I.e. state the problems you see in your current solution.

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing any problems with it, but as I mention, I am not experienced so maybe there /are/ problems with it!